# ActorRefs.Nobody being translated by remoting

Tags: akka.net

I'm using Akka.Remote to call from an ASP.NET web application to an actor in my back end (hosted as a Windows Service). As part of the code I'm looking up an actor on the remote system which may or may not exist.

On the client the call is as follows...

```
var profileActor = await someRemoteActor.Ask<IActorRef>(new LoadProfile("me@here.com"));

if (profileActor != ActorRefs.Nobody)
{
  // Now do stuff with the profile
  ...
}
```

On the remote side of things the code is doing this...

```
Receive<LoadProfile>(rq =>
{
  IActorRef child = ActorRefs.Nobody;
  if (ProfileExistsInTheDatabase(rq.Username))
  {
    child = Context.ActorOf<Profile>(rq.Username);
    child.Tell(rq);
  }

  Sender.Tell(child);
};
```

This isn't the exact code, but shows the idea that if something is not found on the server side then ActorRefs.Nobody is returned.

Now, the problem is that when ActorRefs.Nobody gets back to the client, it's been converted into a remote actor reference, which I wasn't expecting. I was expecting ActorRefs.Nobody to traverse the remoting layer and turn up as the same thing on the client.

Am I wrong to expect this to work this way? I guess so, given that it doesn't work the way I expected, but some clarification would be nice.

For now I've altered the code to return a message class that includes a flag to indicate whether the remote actor exists, but I'd rather be able to use ActorRefs.Nobody.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActorRefs.Nobody might not be converted back to Nobody.Instance in the remote system.

As a workaround, you could compare profileActor.Path to ActorRefs.Nobody.Path instead.

You could file an issue about this on the GitHub repo, this is something that could be fixed in the Remote layer.